# What type of distribution for epsilon? can I generate observations for epsilon?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions, density-function

$X$  has zero truncated poission distribution ($\lambda$)

then pmf is $f(x)=\frac{\lambda^x}{(e^\lambda-1)x!}$

and the probability generating function is $\phi_X(s)=\frac{e^{\lambda s}-1}{e^\lambda-1}$,

Now i have anthor variable $\epsilon$ has the probability generating function

$\phi_\epsilon(s)=\frac{\phi_X(s)}{e^{-\lambda}+(1-e^{-\lambda})\phi_X(1-\alpha+\alpha s)}=\frac{e^{\lambda s}-1}{(1-e^\lambda)e^{\lambda(1-\alpha+\alpha s)}}$

and then $\epsilon$ has the pmf as $P(\epsilon=j)=\frac{[(1-\alpha)^j-(-\alpha)^j]\lambda^j e^{\lambda \alpha}}{j! (e^\lambda-1)}$......  λ>0 and 0≤α≤1/2

What type of distribution for epsilon?  can I generate observations for epsilon ?

Comment: Dear Jean Marie. I am a new user of this page, and I am not good at dealing with it as required until now. I responded to your comment and apologized to you, and this was my response"  am very sorry for the delay in responding. I have a problem in communicating .. Nobody hates cooperation. I thank you very much for your cooperation. Please accept my apologies" ..

Comment: I could not explain the issue again in Comment after your important instructions. I wanted to put a new question and what is meant by it is you because you are the closest to my problem, but there is no mention of a name like Facebook .. Please accept my apology for the second time and help me with my problem ..

Comment: It's all right now. I erase my first comment.

Comment: There should no longer be the term $\color{red}{(1-e^\lambda)}$ in $\phi_\epsilon(s)=\frac{\phi_X(s)}{\phi_X(1-\alpha+\alpha s)}=\frac{e^{\lambda s}-1}{\color{red}{(1-e^\lambda)}e^{\lambda(1-\alpha+\alpha s)}}$ (it is cancelled in the quotient operation).

Comment: I followed the proof more than once, but it already exists. "I can send it to you if you like". This part is also taken from a research that has already been published.The question in the other part, which is  $P(\epsilon=j)=\frac{[(1-\alpha)^j-(-\alpha)^j]\lambda^j e^{\lambda \alpha}}{j! (e^\lambda-1)}$ What type of distribution for epsilon? can I generate observations for epsilon ?

Comment: You mean you try to understand a certain proof. On which type of document (book, article, lecture notes ?...)

Comment: sorry .. $\phi_\epsilon(s)=\frac{\phi_X(s)}{e^{-\lambda}+(1-e^{-\lambda})\phi_X(1-\alpha+\alpha s)}

Comment: The first part of an article but there is an amendment in my post \phi_\epsilon(s)=\frac{\phi_X(s)}{e^{-\lambda}+(1-e^{-\lambda})\phi_X(1-\alpha+\alpha s)}

Comment: Do you know you can modify the text of your question ?

Comment: Post has been modified

Comment: For the simulation, do you know the [inverse transform method] (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399195/how-does-the-inverse-transform-method-work-in-discrete-r-v) applied to discrete random variables ?

Comment: No. I work with time series and not a specialist in distributions. Is it difficult to find the distribution of  epsilon?